# Underscore debounce vs vanilla Javascript setTimeout

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, settimeout, lodash, delayed-execution

I understand that `debounce` in Undercore.js returns a function that will postpone its execution until the wait time is over.

My question is, is there an advantage of using `debounce` over the regular `setTimeout` function in vanilla Javascript? Don't they both work the same?

Comment: They are *significantly* different. I suggest you reread the documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce (and note that [debounce uses setTimeout under the hood](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/012fe2b77e3d206d763c0c078d3b97a63639fc24/underscore.js#L855))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are very different and used in completely different cases.

1. `_.debounce` returns a `function`, `setTimeout` returns an `id` which you can use to cancel the timeOut.
2. No matter how many times you call the function which is returned by _.debounce, it will run only once in the given time frame.

```js
var log_once = _.debounce(log, 5000);

function log() {
  console.log('prints');
}

log_once();
log_once();
log_once();
log_once();
log_once();

var id = setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('hello');
}, 3000);
clearTimeout(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just FYI, [**This Vanilla `debounce`**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/debounce) method returns the Timeout so you can cancel it manually if you choose too.

Answer (score 12):

`setTimeout` and `debounce` are in no way the same thing. `setTimeout` simply waits `n` milliseconds and the invokes the supplied function. `debounce` on the other hand returns a function that only calls the callback after `n` milliseconds **after the last time the functions was called**.

Huge difference. Debouncing/throttling (they are not the same thing) functions are often used to reduced the amount of function calls as a result of user input. Imagine a autocomplete/typeahead field. You might do an ajax request every keystroke, but that can get kind of heavy, so instead you can debounce the function, so it will only fire 200ms **after** the last keystroke.

You can read up on the documentation here: https://lodash.com/docs#debounce

Comment: ...unless your event handler first cancels the timeout and then resets it. Then, you effectively have the same behavior.

Comment: you can achieve the debounce functionality with setTimeout and clearTimeout.
You assign the setTimeout into a variable and use clearTimeout above the variable declaration. 

let timer;

function SetTimer(){
  clearTimeout(timer); // the clearTimeout will work if timer hs been assign before
  timer = setTimeout(() => console.log("here"), 1000);
};

Answer (score 10):

You can also implement your own debounce in vanilla JavaScript. A widely quoted article is David Walsh's article on [function debouncing with underscore](https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce) which includes the source code used by underscore in their implementation:

```js
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

The debounce function serves as a generator for the actual function you'd like to call, that way the state can be persisted inside of the closure like this:

```js
// example function
let sayHello = (name) => console.log(`Hi ${name}`)

// generate a debounced version with a min time between calls of 2 seconds
let sayHelloDebounced = debounce(sayHello, 2000)

// call however you want
sayHelloDebounced('David')
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
 };
};

let sayHello = (name) => console.log(`Hi ${name}`)

let sayHelloDebounced = debounce(sayHello, 2000)

sayHelloDebounced('David')
sayHelloDebounced('David')
sayHelloDebounced('David')
```

#### Other Implementations

- [Underscore Docs](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce) | [Underscore Source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.10.2/modules/index.js#L884-L911)
- [Lodash Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) | [Lodash Source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15-npm/debounce.js#L66-L87)
- [30 Seconds of Code](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/debounce)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will run once after n seconds passed. So if you call setTimeout 4 times, it will run 4 times. Debounce on the other hand it will be called only once.
[image]

In formal English debounce does what setTimeout and clearTiemout do together.
If you don't want to use debounce you can use setTimeout together with clearTiemout to achieve the same behavior.

```
let timer; 
function setTimer(){ 
  clearTimeout(timer); 
  timer = setTimeout(() => console.log("here"), 1000); 
};
setTimer();
setTimer();
setTimer();
setTimer();
// here
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I came across a blog post which has much clearer explanation on debounce and throttle. Do check it out if above answers seems confusing. It helped me clear my doubts.
[Debounce and Throttle in Javascript](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-debounce-and-throttle-in-javascript-da95dc151f7b)