# How to track in Google Analytics what data the user entered in the input?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to show in Google Analytics the values that the user enters in the fields. But I do not need to see the number of clicks on the field. Help me please.

Comment: Tracking text field values in GA is usually a terrible idea, since users may enter personally identifiable data which you are not allowed to store in GA per Google's terms of service. Can you elaborate on your use case ? Implementing this would be fairly trivial, but I don't want really want to make an answer if implementing this will potentially get you in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Eike . My form is a simple custom calculator. No secret data is not entered there. I need to know what numbers users enter. I need this for statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably combine the approach here: [How to get text of an input text box during onKeyPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress)

With a ga event send.

Answer (score 2):

## Sending Data to Google Programmatically

Google has two major analytics implementations: [**analytics.js**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) & [**gtag.js**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs) - depending on which you're using, there's a different syntax for each to log page views.  You could also probably log an event as well.

#### Analytics.js - [page views](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)

```js
ga('send', 'pageview', [page], [fieldsObject]);
```

#### Gtag.js - [pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages)

```js
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'page_title' : 'homepage',
  'page_path': '/home'
});
```

## Handling the Event in Javascript

Your use case will determine which events you'd like to use to trigger logging.  Handling the `blur` event is fine for most use cases, but you also might want to handle text change and then debounce

#### Debouncing

Here's a [discussion and vanilla js implementation of debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61241621/1366033) based off [underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.10.2/modules/index.js#L884-L911):

```js
function debounce(func, wait) {
  var timeoutId;

  return function() {
      var context = this,
          args = arguments;

      clearTimeout(timeoutId);

      timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        func.apply(context, args);
      }, wait);  
  };
};
```

#### Example in Stack Snippets

```js
// generate a debounced version with a min time between calls of 2 seconds
let sendPageView = debounce(function() {
    gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
        'page_title' : 'homepage',
        'page_path': '/home?searchText=' + encodeURI(filter.value)
    });
    console.log("Text: " + filter.value)
}, 2000)

// attach event listener
let filter = document.getElementById("filter")
filter.addEventListener('input', sendPageView)


function debounce(func, wait) {
  var timeoutId;

  return function() {
      var context = this,
          args = arguments;
          
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      
      timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        func.apply(context, args);
      }, wait);  
  };
};


// fake gtag for demo
gtag = function() {}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter" />
```